# Mapping an Array of jQuery objects not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

```
<ul id="source">
  <li>北京空气质量：<b>90</b></li>
  <li>上海空气质量：<b>70</b></li>
  <li>天津空气质量：<b>80</b></li>
  <li>广州空气质量：<b>50</b></li>
  <li>深圳空气质量：<b>40</b></li>
  <li>福州空气质量：<b>32</b></li>
  <li>成都空气质量：<b>90</b></li>
</ul>
```

My goal is to retrieve information from `<ul>...</ul>` in the html file. The data format should be like:`[["北京",90],["上海",70],.....]` an array of arrays with the first elements are the substring from the Chinese text and the second elements are the numbers.

My idea of using jQuery on this is

```
function getData() {
    /*
     coding here
     */
    var sourceData = $("#source").find("li");
    /*
     data = [
     ["北京", 90],
     ["北京", 90]
     ……
     ]
     */

    return sourceData.map(function (item) {
        return [$(item).text().substring(0,2),$(item).find("b").text()];
    });
```

It returned `["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""]`.

So I began to exam where it went wrong. First I tried it without jQuery like this

```
function getData() {
var rowData = document.getElementById("source").getElementsByTagName("li");
var sourceData = [].slice.apply(rowData);
sourceData.map(function (item) {
        return [$(item).text().substring(0, 2), $(item).find("b").text()];
    });
```

and it worked. So I started to test

```
var sourceData = $("#source").find("li");
sourceData.map(item => item);
```

and the return was `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`. I thought maybe the return of `var sourceData = $("#source").find("li");` was not an `Array` but

```
> sourceData.__proto__
< []
```

I'm confused. Anyone can help? Thanks!

Comment: What is expected output?

Comment: More explanation, please :/

Comment: Change it to `return sourceData.toArray().map`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/rprjcng1/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to jQuery document http://api.jquery.com/map/, the callback of map function is a little different with native ES array map. The callback arguments explanation as below:

```
Type: Function( Integer index, Element domElement ) => Object
A function object that will be invoked for each element in the current set
```

So change your `getData` function as below:

```
return sourceData.map(function (index, item) {
    return [$(item).text().substring(0,2),$(item).find("b").text()];
});
```

Comment: But y the prototype is `[]`? Shouldn't this mean that `sourceData` is an array and its `map()` should be native?

Comment: Yes, but jQuery already override the native map on jQuery object!

Answer (score 0):

This script seems to work:

```
function getData() {

    var sourceData = [];
    $("#source li").each(function (){
        var li_text = $(this).text();
        li_text = li_text.split(":");
        var sData   = [li_text[0].substring(0,2),li_text[1]];
        sourceData.push(sData);
    });
    return sourceData;

}
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Ln6gk0g5/1/)

Comment: Thanks, this one works. But @R Lam 's comment is what I'm looking for. :)